# Consumerseekaware when implemented in spring Kafka 3.1.3 methods not overrided and consumerseekcallback object is returning null

Tags: spring-kafka

Iam trying to receive same message from Kafka for particular condition. I used consumerseekaware by implementing in my class but no methods is overrided and consumerseekcallback is returning null when used.
Iuse spring Kafka 3.1.3

I tried spring Kafka 3.1.3 and I want the consumerseekaware should work and consumerseekcallback should not be null

Comment: If you can provide a small, minimally reproducible sample, we can look into it further.